# how to show product SKU below product name only on product page

Tags: magento-1.9, product, layout, product-attribute

I am using porto theme in magento 1.9. i want to display product SKU only on product page below product name. how can we add product SKU on product page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit file
`app/design/frontend/yourtheme/package/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

if you want to add SKU then please add following code underneath of H1 tag (product name).
`<h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getSku(), 'sku') ?></h1>`

To remove the attribute from details section, comment out the line
`<?php echo $_product->getSku(); ?>`